# SCSS variables to CSS in Ionic 3-4 transition ­— How?

Tags: css, sass, ionic3, ionic4, upgrade

I'm upgrading an Ionic 3 project to Ionic 4 (then later to 5 and 6, but 4 first).
One of the things that I need to do for this is to convert all the SCSS variable-setting to CSS variables. What's the best way to go about this?

(I recognize this is kind of non-specific. I'll add more if needed.)

Comment: convert online scss to css

Comment: Is that a "Google it"?